# Problems using Colorama on Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, colorama

I'm learning to use colorama in Python, so I installed it and I'm able to import the module with no problems from the Primary Prompt.

```
>>> import colorama
>>> from colorama import *
>>> print(Fore.BLUE + 'BLUE TEXT')
 BLUE TEXT
```

Now, if I create a small piece of code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from colorama import *

print(Fore.BLUE + 'BLUE TEXT')
```

I get the following message:

```
File "colorama_Test.py", line 3, in <module>
  from colorama import *
File "/home/olg32/Python/colorama_Test.py", line 5, in <module>
   print(Fore.BLUE + 'BLUE TEXT')
NameError: name 'Fore' is not defined
```

Which tells me that the module is not being found. But as mentioned it was installed and tested successfully from the Primary Prompt. Could it be a path definition issue or something like that? This is the current directory where the module is installed:

```
usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/colorama-0.3.7-py2.7.egg
```

Does this path needs to be defined somewhere? Sorry I'm new on Python.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you have worked out the answer by now but have you tried specifying `Fore`?

When I use the `colorama` module I start with this:

```
import os, colorama
from colorama import Fore,Style,Back #specifying all 3 types
os.system("mode con: cols=120 lines=30") #sometimes colorama doesnt work 
#when double clicking a python app so I use this to "prompt" command line 
#and then it works fine colorama.init() should work too
```

**Example code:**

```
import os, colorama
from colorama import Fore,Style,Back
os.system("mode con: cols=120 lines=30")

print(Fore.RED + 'some red text')
print(Back.GREEN + 'and with a green background')
print(Style.DIM + 'and in dim text')
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
print('back to normal now')
```

If this doesnt work for you let me know :)

Comment: Thanks! yes I found the problem. I was naming my script "colorama.py" that was causing problems with library. Once I changed the name all worked fine. Sorry I'm in the learning phase...

Comment: If this worked for you, do you mind giving it an up vote and accepted answer? Thanks

Comment: @olg32: The error message shown in your question indicates your script was named "colorama_Test.py" so you comment about its name down here doesn't make sense.